# How to make an array when the JSON file does not have any and only got objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to make an app that gets data from url on Android. I noticed that JSON files are different.  Some of them start with an arrach name and some not. Those that have the array name [like this](http://api.learn2crack.com/android/json/) which "user" is the array name work in my app but those that does not have any array name does not work. [For example this](http://api.worldbank.org/countries/ir?format=json).

This is the code that I try to make array an object but it does not work for the second JSON file as it does not find the array name:

```
//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/ir?format=json";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

JSONArray user = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

        //Importing TextView
        final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
        final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);

        //Set JSON Data in TextView
        uid.setText(id);
        name1.setText(name);
        email1.setText(email);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

So this example is for the first JSON part. Can you tell me how to have similar code but for the second JSON file please?

Comment: Which infos from the second file are you interested in?

Comment: @Octoshape Just any. I only want to learn dealing with this kind of files that have arrays and not a object.  I'd get data like, id, name, region, iso2Code

Comment: Are you using the learn2crack library for the JSONParser or did you write one yourself?

Comment: @Octoshape Yes I am using learn2crack library. But I noticed that most of JSONParser's have the same code for HTTP .

Comment: Ok.. I'll have a look at their parser.. do you get any exceptions when you try the url for the second file?

Comment: @Octoshape yes this is the catlog: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.worldbank/com.example.worldbank.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`
   But I belive the problem is all about the way I make arrays and objects.

Comment: Ah I see.. yes you need to use AsyncTasks, but the parser also can't parse JSONArrays .. I will include a solution to both problems in my answer below.

Comment: @user2977338 you have to use thread/asynctask when you do any network operation as Octoshape suggested.

Comment: @user2977338 you can use either Octoshape or my solution. Both solution have their own uniqueness :)

Comment: @user2977338 if you need some sample code to get you started on the AsyncTask thing let me know I can add some to my answer below.

Comment: @Octoshape Thanks for your help. I tried your solution did not work unfortunately. It would be great if you provide some sample code for AsyncTask as I have no idea about it.  An also why learn2crack did not use it asyncTask ?! What he used is a different way ? or because the json file is small ?!

Comment: @user2977338 I'll explain the AsyncTask more detailed in my answer, it's nothing in learn2crack's code that's wrong. I'll explain it.

Comment: @user2977338 I've updated my answer, have a look at the section between [EDIT] and [/EDIT].

Comment: As this question is more about AsyncTask and not the array problem of this app. I am going to create a new post specifically for the array problem.

Comment: So did you get the AsyncTask running now? Would be glad if you could select an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you're not allowed to do Network stuff on the main thread because those things tend to take long (if the server is not responding or the connection is bad or the file you are trying to fetch is big) and if done on the main thread it will block the application on the phone. If your app is not responsive for too long it will be killed automatically from the Android OS. In order to avoid such things you need to use AsyncTasks. These are tasks that can do work in the background while your main thread is still being responsive to user input.

You can read more about AsyncTasks [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

[EDIT]
So answering to your comment on your question: The reason why you get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is because you call `jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` in your main thread (the one where you execute code normally). The reason why this is not allowed is because in the method `getJSONFromUrl()` you make a HTTP request and have to wait for a response from the given URL. This can take a very long time as I have explained above and would block your application on the phone with the already explained consequences. Now to fix this you need to do something like this:

**Before (bad):**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Creating new JSON Parser
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// Getting JSON from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

// get the data from your JSONObject

}
```

**Better:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Getting JSON from URL
new JsonRequest().execute(url);

}

private class JsonRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>
// I will talk about the parameters to AsyncTask below
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        return json;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

        // Get the array
        JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("data");

        // Display the data
        // Import textviews
        // and so on..
    }
```

Now about the parameters to `AsyncTask`:

1. This type is the type of the parameters given to `doInBackground`
2. This type is used for showing a progress bar for example if you download many things you can override a function called `onProgressUpdate` and could show how many things already have been downloaded on your app so the user knows that something is happening.
3. This type is the type that `doInBackground` will return and that `onPostExecute` has as a parameter.

This way your main thread will keep running and the user won't notice a thing that there is a download going on in the background because it's a seperate task that is running. I hope this made it quite clear if not, just leave another comment and I'll explain more. :)

[\EDIT]

Then the second problem is that the `JSONParser` from learn2crack can't parse JSONArrays, in other words the function `getJSONFromUrl()` simply tries to create a new `JSONObject` from the `String` it gets from the given url.

Theres basically several ways to fix this, I did a little hack (it invovles little code but you will need more time getting to the data afterwards). I added the following lines into the `getJSONFromUrl()` method:

```
if (json.startsWith("[")) {
    // We have a JSONArray
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject();
        jObj.put("data", new JSONArray(json));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("JSON Parser", "Error parsing JSONArray " + e.toString());
    }
    return jObj;
}
```

These lines should be added right above this part:

```
// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

Basically what you will end up with then is that you can simply call `getJSONFromUrl()` on any url, and if it contains a `JSONObject` you will get that object, but if it contains a `JSONArray` you will get a `JSONObject` with a single field called `data` which will contain your `JSONArray`. So you could do something like this:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");
```

And then you have your array (of course surrounded with a try catch for `JSONException`).

Comment: I liked the solution of yours too i was thinking more in terms of interface so i can return one object instead of two object from getJSONFromUrl. Your's one is more shorter way :)

Comment: Thanks for your post. Only a question. I added the _if-statement_ and `try{ jObj ....` in the `getJSONFromUrl` method. but it came up with error like `json` and `jObj` are not defined and declared.  Why is that ?

Comment: @user2977338 Can you please post me your full `getJSONFromUrl` method code in your question above?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really helpful and made my app running

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know there is no specific way to tell whether you are getting json array or json object after you parse it!!!.

The way i would solve this,is to look for starting character of the string data from response.

In your getJSONFromUrl method you get the string from response and then you start parse it into an JsonObject. Before you parse look for starting character based on starting character decide whether you are going for JsonObject or JsonArray.

Am not sure if their is any shorter way to solve this but your problem is a tricky one :) .A lot of other things have to be dealt with since you don't actually know beforehand whether you are going to get jsonobject or jsonarray.

Here is what i have put together:

```
public interface JsonListener {

     public boolean isJsonObejct();

}
```

Create a class by extending JSONObject and implementing the above interface.

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class CustomJSONObject extends JSONObject implements JsonListener {

public CustomJSONObject(String json) throws JSONException {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(json);
}

@Override
public boolean isJsonObejct() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

 }
```

Create another class by extending JSONArray and implementing the above interface.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class CustomJSONArray extends JSONArray implements JsonListener{

public CustomJSONArray(String json) throws JSONException {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(json);
}

@Override
public boolean isJsonObejct() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

 }
```

Modify you jsonparseclass so it does not return jsonobject or jsonarray instead it will return Object of type JsonListener.

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JsonListener jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JsonListener getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        if(json.startsWith("{")){
            jObj = new CustomJSONObject(json);
        }else{
            jObj = new CustomJSONArray(json);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
 }
```

Now adjust your code to use those:

```
// Creating new JSON Parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JsonListener json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            if(json.isJsonObejct()){
                Log.i("Got","JsonObject "+((CustomJSONObject)json).toString());
            }else{
                Log.i("Got","JsonArray "+((CustomJSONArray)json).toString());
            }
```

Hopefully you will get some insight from this.

Comment: Nice use of interfaces. Like the idea!

Comment: Thanks for your post. But it did not work. Just a few questions to make sure I did it correctly. Where should I add my JSONListener in? I add it at the end of the Main_Activity. and also should I remove this line? `value = json.getJSONArray(VALUE);`

Comment: JSONListener will be a separate file. And as for getting data from json you have to use ((CustomJSONObject)json).get[Type of Data you need] or ((CustomJSONArray)json).get[Type of Data you need]. You will find all the getters in documentation. I think it's better if you use @Octoshape solution because it's much lighter then mine in terms of code you have to write.But to know how you might take advantage of interface in situation like this you can use this one. :)

Comment: @saiful103a thanks for the advertising :D I still prefer your solution over mine because of the genericity by returning a JsonListener...